# How can I set the name of a process created with CreateProcess?

Tags: c++, createprocess

I am starting a process with CreateProcess following the formulas found on google.  What I am wondering, is can I set the process name of the created process so that it is obvious in the task manager?

Thank you,
--Douglas

Comment: Windows processes (and others too), doesn't have names, they have only id. But system allows you using the id find out what executable is running and use name (path) of the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an available option.  The process name as visible in Task Manager is derived from the file name.  If you want another name to show up then simply rename the EXE file.

Comment: unfortunately, the exe is javaw.exe which calls my jar file.  If someone has multiple java programs running, they will not know which one is mine.

Answer (score -1):

For getting process name, you should use psapi.dll

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/process-status-helper